# Right click (menu) in PowerBuilder

Tags: powerbuilder

I have created a menu item when you right click.  I need to call a stored procedure when clicking the menu item, the stored proc will then bring back a list comparing items.
How do I call the proc (once clicked the menu item) and open the window to display the results.  I have created an event but do not know what to put in the event.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Create a datawindow that calls the SP as its source.  In the menu event, you can call a window function that instantiates a datastore, binds it to SQLCA, and retrieves the result set.  If you need to show the result set on the screen, sharedata() to a datawindow control that has the same dw object.

-Paul Horan-
SAP